# Angular 2 ContentChildren select the host element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a nav list component that is trying to get the content children of the same type.

```
<nav-list>
    <nav-list>
        <div>
            <nav-item>item1</nav-item>
        </div>
        <nav-item>Item 2</nav-item>
    </nav-list>
</nav-list>

export class NavListComponent {
   @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => NavListComponent)) childNavList;
}
```

The problem is that the `host` itself also includes in the `childNavList`. So in the above example, the `childNavList` length is two.

I thought `ContentChildren` supposed to get only the children, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is a [bug report in Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10098) opened for this a long time ago. Look into the discussion on there where the current workaround is to filter out the current component from the list when working with the `QueryList`.

Examples people used in that thread are:

```
.filter(x => x !== this)
```

or

```
.filter(x => x.element.nativeElement !== this.element.nativeElement)
```

Comment: .filter((list) => list !== this); => empty array

Comment: Are you working with it before the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook has executed?

Comment: In ngAfterContentInit. Without the filter, I'm getting two items.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing differently, but here is an Plunker that shows the behavior working... https://plnkr.co/edit/E0xtYKxsa6OJodb0QZX9